# Issue with image url

Tags: jquery, html

I am developing a web application using netbeans,in that i need to display an image. If i place the image in **/web** folder it is displaying the image but while placing the image like this **C:/1.jpg** not displaying .....

But i put the image at C:/ and even i tested this url in web browser and in file manager. It is displaying the corresponding image while using in the application it is not showing..!!
What is the problem??

this is my code

```
 %><tr><td></td><td id="C:/1.jpg" class="options" style="cursor:pointer"><%=salespersons[sub]%></td></tr><%
```

and corresponding jquery is,

```
           $("td.options").hover(function(){                            
                var imgsrc= $(this).attr('id');
                $("#photo").attr('src',imgsrc);
           });
```

and

```
      </center><div id="imagediv"><img src="" id="photo" alt="No Image Found" width="100" height="100"/></div><center>
```

Comment: your image can not reside on your local harddriive. it has to be on the server

Comment: @konsolenfreddy: is it mandatory??

Comment: @user636207 are you working on server or not?

Comment: @user636207 yes .. iam working on server(Application server:Apache tomcat)

Comment: If you're working on a server you can't access local files, otherwise websites would read out all passwords which are saved in your browser because the path is always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have any file outside the project folder, it will not be loaded by server when you deploy the project so its not accessed. If you want these files to be loaded you should include the complete path in the server configuration file to load these files explicitly by server  while starting the server.

Answer (score 1):

You would never want to specify a drive specific location when coding as it wouldn't be very portable. Stick to using the relative paths.

But to answer the question to access local drive you need to prefix the url with file.

```
file:///C:/1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your webRoot is it /web or c:\ ?
the image in c:\ works with browser and file manager with file:///image.ext 
it is not a good practice to access resources like this. you can put images in /web/images folder.

if you still wan to access images from file:///C:/image.EXT. make sure that apache have read write access on C:\ drive